# Thinkpad T480 touchpad: enable vertical scroll (no DE), which config to use?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, xinput, synaptic, libinput

I don't know if im using libinput or synaptics cause i use both at the same time.

**Xorg synaptic config**

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf 
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        # OWN SHIT
        Option "PalmDetect" "1"
        Option "PalmMinWidth" "3"
        Option "PalmMinZ" "50"
        Option "VertScrollDelta" "30"
        Option "HorizScrollDelta" "500"

# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
#       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
        # OWN SHIT
        Option "PalmDetect" "1"
        Option "PalmMinWidth" "4"
        Option "PalmMinZ" "50"
        Option "VertScrollDelta" "30"
        Option "HorizScrollDelta" "500"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

**Altough i set the scroll speed with this script**:

```
#!bin/bash
# MOUSE SCRIPT
# xinput, permanent, run at startup
# touchpad scroll speed config

# >> TOUCHPAD
# Scroll speed
xinput set-prop "Synaptics TM3276-022" "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" 300, 100

# >> TRACKPOINT
# Scroll speed
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 50
```

**And i set the trackpoint speed with this script**

```
#!bin/bash
# Trackpoint speed controll config
xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "libinput Accel Profile Enab
led" 1, 0

xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "libinput Accel Speed" 0.40
```

**Any idea which config to use or which is the config the system uses?**

Answer (score 0):

`libinput` and `synaptics`can lead to conflicts and unexpected behavior. To ensure that your touchpad settings are consistent and that you're using the desired driver, you should consider simplifying your configuration.

Determine which driver you want to use: libinput or synaptics. It's generally recommended to use libinput as it's the modern driver for input devices in Linux.

Remove conflicting configurations: Remove either the libinput or synaptics configuration file, depending on your choice of driver. To do this, you can delete one of the configuration files from `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
```

or

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

Adjust touchpad settings using the chosen driver: Once you've removed the conflicting configuration, you can adjust touchpad settings using the remaining driver. You can do this through a single configuration file for the chosen driver.

For example, if you're using libinput, create a configuration file for libinput in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/. Name it something like 40-libinput-custom.conf and add your libinput touchpad settings there.

If you decide to use synaptics, create a synaptics configuration file in the same directory with your desired settings.

Restart to ensure that the changes take effect

Comment: Thank your! Is synaptic/libinput conflicts with xinput?

Comment: Using both configurations could lead to conflicts.